# How to set default Container size relative to the breakpoint in Chakra UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, containers, size, chakra-ui

I am exploring Chakra UI in my React project. But I'm unable to figure out how to make the Container size/width relatively limited to the breakpoint by default.

I can set the maxW prop to the Container to stop expanding width. But the problem is, every time I use a Container component, I have to set the maxW every time. I don't want to repeat that. Instead, I want the Container size to be as the breakpoint defined and it will be responsive based on the breakpoint.

How can I do that?

Here is my main.tsx and App.tsx files.

```
// main.tsx

import { ChakraProvider, extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

// Extend theme
const breakpoints = {
    sm: "320px",
    md: "768px",
    lg: "960px",
    xl: "1200px",
    "2xl": "1536px",
};

const theme = extendTheme({ breakpoints });

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
            <App />
        </ChakraProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
// App.tsx

import { Container } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Container maxW='8xl'>
            <h1>Hello project</h1>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default App;
```